# Search a string using 2 different delimiters - C Programming

Tags: c

I want to search through a string of text in C and find out where text falls between 2 different delimiters. I specifically looking for a comments falling between /* and */. I cannot find a function which will allow me to use 2 different delimiters each of 2 characters long.

I currently have a a very long char[] and I need to search through it. The closest thing I can find is strstr to find the first occurrence of "/*" and then use it again with "*/" instead. However, this completely omits the whole comment and just gives me the "*/" and the rest of the code.

```
char *pch;
char *pch2;
pch = strstr(wholeProgramStr, "/*");
printf("%s\n",pch);
pch2 = strstr(pch, "*/");
printf("%s\n",pch2);
```

Any ideas? and the same question but between "//" and a newline character. I can't find a way of implementing this without have some very messy and inefficient code.

Comment: Your idea to use `strstr` is basically good. What do you want to do with the found string? Do you want to process (e.g. print) it, do you want to remove it from the original string? Can you modify the original string (as `strtok` does) to place a terminating null character after the comment? Should the delimiters be included in the found string?

Comment: I basically need to take the string and be able to count the amount of characters used to make it up excluding the /* */. I can't modify the input. Thanks

Comment: Okay, then `pch2 - (pch + 2)` will give you the answer, where the `2` is the string length of the starting delimiters `/*` or `//`. (You should probably start searching for `pch2` at `pch + 2`, too to catch the degenerate comment `/*/`. And check whether they are there at all, otherwise you could pass `NULL` to the second `strstr`.)

Comment: What delimiter would I use for a newline. Because some comments start with // and end with a newline

Comment: The right delimiter would be `"\n"` in this case, a string that contains only the new-line character, `'\n'`.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea to use `strstr` is good, but it doesn't give you a null-terminated string. It gives you a pointer to the beginning of the string and the string's length via pointer arithmetic. You can print a char array that is limited by its length by specifying a width with the `%s` format in `printf`:

```
void str_print_between(const char *str, 
    const char *left, const char *right)
{
    const char *begin, *end;
    int len; 

    begin = strstr(str, left);
    if (begin == NULL) return;
    begin += strlen(left);

    end = strstr(begin, right);
    if (end == NULL) return;

    len = end - begin;
    printf("'%.*s'\n", len, begin);
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you can return both start pointer and length (via pointers or as a `struct`) from your function. There are many `strn*` functions that act equivalent to their `str*` counterparts, but take an additional maximum length, so you could use those to process your string further.

Treating line comments works just the same as with block comments, just with other delimiters. (But this simple solution does not heed the context; it will detect comments in or across strings, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

```
char *tmp = strdup(wholeProgramStr); /* makes a copy to be writeable */
char *pch;
char *pch2;

pch = strstr(tmp, "/*"); /* pointer to first occurrence */
if (pch) { /* founded */
    pch += 2; /* skip "/*" */
    pch2 = strstr(pch, "*/"); /* pointer to second occurrence */
    if (pch2) { /* founded */
        *pch2 = '\0'; /* cut */
        printf("%s\n", pch);
    }
}
```

As pointed out by @alk, there is no need to duplicate the string if you only need to print the result:

```
char *pch;
char *pch2;

pch = strstr(wholeProgramStr, "/*"); /* pointer to first occurrence */
if (pch) { /* founded */
    pch += 2; /* skip "/*" */
    pch2 = strstr(pch, "*/"); /* pointer to second occurrence */
    if (pch2) { /* founded */
        printf("%*s\n", pch2 - pch, pch));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

> How would I run this again until it reaches the end of the string? So
>   it can find multiple comments?

Loop until you don't find both delimiters:

```
char *tmp = wholeProgramStr;
char *pch;

while (1) {
    pch = strstr(tmp, "/*"); /* pointer to first occurrence */
    if (pch) { /* founded */
        pch += 2; // skip "/*"
        tmp = strstr(pch, "*/"); /* pointer to second occurrence */
        if (tmp) { /* founded */
            printf("%*s\n", tmp - pch, pch));
            tmp += 2; // skip "*/"
        } else break;
    } else break;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: Why the duplication? You could use `... "%*s\n", pch2-pch-2, pch)`. to only print out some the comment.

Comment: How would I run this again until it reaches the end of the string? So it can find multiple comments?

Comment: Can you explain what the if(pch) means. I don't get what you mean by founded?

Comment: `if (pch)` --> `if (pch != NULL)` --> if string contains a delimiter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64534/discussion-between-jamesdonnelly-and-alter-mann).