# Ignoring characters after a spcific character with sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I've got string data in the form of: garbageFLAG=USEFUL INFO;garbage

I want to extract the useful info into a string called `value`. So far I have `sscanf(value, "%[^FLAG=]=%s;%*[^\n]", value, garbage);`
which ignores the garbage at the beginning but still picks up the garbage at the end. I'm at a loss of what the proper [ ] notation should be to ignore everything after USEFUL INFO as well.

Comment: `scanf` and friends are not a good match for this task.

Comment: Using `strstr` will show you where `"FLAG:"` begins, and `strchr` from that place will find you the `';'` terminator, which you can overwrite with `'\0'`. Then you can get the useful info with `strcpy`. I don't see why you are extracting the trailing garbage from a string source - it's not a stream that has to be cleared.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Search a string using 2 different delimiters - C Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26815623/https://stackoverflow.com/q/26815623/90527)", "[How to extract some formatted string from the buffer using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68423198/90527)"

Comment: The sample has some fixable issues. The `%[...]` specifiers still need variables to scan into. The format string doesn't match `"FLAG"` before the `'='`.

Comment: The sample also has some (potential) non-fixable issues, hence n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.'s comment. The `%s` specifier in the `scanf` family will stop at the first space, so will never work if `"USEFUL INFO"` might contain spaces.  Similarly, if `"FLAG"` is multiple characters, then `%[^FLAG=]` will potentially stop matching too early.